# Multiprocessing program runs only single process

Tags: python

I come from a java background, but I've done a fair bit of research on multiprocessing in python and still having trouble. I have a class:

```
class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def run(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
        # do stuff that takes a bit
```

a 2d array of the args `arg_array`

then eventually I call:

```
pool = mp.Pool(24)
for i in range(len(args_array)):
     pool.apply_async(Test.run(args_array[i][0], args_array[i][1], args_array[i][2], args_array[i][3]))
```

This is just a simplified version of the program. However the program still only ends up using a single core (6% of my CPU)

I also tried:

```
pool.apply_async(Test.run, args=(args_array[i][0], args_array[i][1], args_array[i][2], args_array[i][3]))
```

EDIT:
As requested, I made another (simpler) working program with the same problem:

```
class Searcher:
    @staticmethod
    def linear_search(array_to_search, target_value):
        print("beginning search")
        for i in range(len(array_to_search)):
            time.sleep(1)  # delay to make things interesting
            if array_to_search[i] == target_value:
                print("Value was found!")
                return True
        print("Value was not found")
        return False


def generate_random_array(size, value_range):
    array = []
    for i in range(size):
        array.append(r.randint(1, value_range))
    return array


if __name__ == '__main__':
    some_arbitrary_number = 50
    random_arrays = []
    for i in range(some_arbitrary_number):
        random_arrays.append(generate_random_array(10, 5))  # array of 10 numbers ranging 1-5

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=24)
    for i in range(len(random_arrays)):
        result = pool.apply_async(Searcher.linear_search, args=(random_arrays[i], 3))  # search for 3 in this array
        result.get(10)
```

this program simply generates a bunch of randomly generated arrays and checks to see if they contain they value 3. However I would like all of these searches to happen in parallel, so my output would look like

```
beginning search
beginning search
beginning search
...
beginning search
Value was found!
Value was not found!
...
```

However I am getting:

```
beginning search
Value was found!
beginning search
Value was found!
beginning search
```

The program only uses one core, I want it to use 24.

Comment: You workload is rather tiny compared to the overhead of creating a process. you will never get useful metrics with that. More importantly you are executing everything synchronously in your call. You have to give a **callable** to `apply_async` not a full call.

Comment: @KlausD. This isn't the actual program, the workload of Test.run is much, much larger in my actual program.

Comment: As a side note, call `Test.run(*args_array[i])`.

Comment: @DYZ tried that and got `TypeError: run() argument after * must be an iterable, not int`

Comment: @KlausD. what do you mean by apply callable to apply_async and not a full call?

Comment: @DontJudgeMe Have you read the multiprocessing docs? I think you need a guide or a tutorial, which isn't what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: @AMC Yes I have, and I'm still having trouble, so I come here and asked my question.

Comment: Please provide an actual example of `args_array` (since the error message you claim you get doesn't match your description of it) and put the example code together so that it produces the error in a reproducible way.

Comment: To add to the comment by @Grismar, here is the relevant part of the help center: [mcve]

Comment: @Grismar the last two args are very, very large 2d arrays. But an actual output I got was `[3, 1, 1, 1] 1 [*insert large 2d array*] [*insert large 2d array*]

Comment: @DontJudgeMe I'm sure, but I doubt the size of the array is causing your problem or has anything to do with the solution, so if you provide an example that has the same problem but not as much data, people will be able to point out your exact issue instead of having a "yes it is, not it isn't" type conversation in the comments

Comment: @Grismar an actual `args_array` but simplified would look like `[3, 1, 1, 1] 1 [[1,2],[3,4]] [[5,6],[7,8]]`

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you refuse to play by the (simple and fair) rules, I can't help you - that's not even a valid python expression and you're clearly ignoring people's requests to simply update you example code to make sense

Comment: @Grismar Sorry im not trying to be spiteful/rude, i'm just not sure what I can provide to make it more the problem more clear rather than more complicated (its a complicated program that I don't entirely understand myself despite making it). And its not an expression, its just the output of `print(args_array[i])` with the last two arguments shortened.

Comment: @AMC The code above is the minimized/relevant version of the code, however I suppose I could try making another simpler program for just the problem I have, I'll try to make something then upload it for you to check out.

Comment: @DontJudgeMe It may be _minimized/relevant_, but it isn't complete nor runnable, that's the issue.

Comment: @AMC check my edit

Comment: Why are you calling result.get right after apply_async? This will block the calling process until the job is done. You should gather the promises from apply_async in an array and then .get them all in a separate loop. That way all the applies will happen in parallel.

Comment: @nneonneo bingo that did it for the new program I made! This is the solution. Thanks m8

Comment: I hope this stresses the importance of posting a proper MCVE - you assumed the error was on the `apply_async` line and posted that alone, when the problem lay elsewhere.

Comment: Why is `linear_search` part of a class? Does the use of a class make more sense in the actual program?

Comment: @AMC Yes you're right, in the actual program I use a static class to hold some variables that the function uses.

Comment: @DontJudgeMe A static class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you call `.get` immediately after `.apply_async`. What you're basically telling Python is to launch one task on the pool, and then wait for that task to finish before launching the next one - so of course you'll only end up running one thing at a time.

The correct way to use `apply_async` is to collect all of the *promise* objects that it returns, and then `.get` them in a separate loop:

```py
promises = [pool.apply_async(Searcher.linear_search, args=(arr, 3) for arr in random_arrays]
for p in promises:
    p.get()
```

or, even simpler, just use `Pool.starmap`:

```py
for result in pool.starmap(Searcher.linear_search, ((arr, 3) for arr in random_arrays)):
    print(result)
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to use a context manager to handle the pool eh.